# Generic parameter returns List<ChildInterface> in stream, but direct method call returns List<Parent>

Tags: list, generics, lambda, java-8, generic-list

For setup, I have :

```
interface Parent

interface Child1 extends Parent

interface Child2 extends Parent
```

And elsewhere I have:

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<Child1> child1List = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Parent> getChild1List(Contact contact) {
        return child1List.parallelStream()
                         .filter(m -> m.getContacts().contains(contact))
                         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Parent::getParentField))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

When I do it this way, getChild1List returns a `List<Parent>` (Shouldn't it return `List<Child1>`?)

Later, I found that stream to be useful for other methods, so I extracted it and built a generic method with it. I have multiple interfaces that extend Parent, so I did as follows:

```
    private <T extends Parent> List<T> returnsListByContact(List<T> childList, Contact contact) {
        return childList.parallelStream()
                        .filter(m -> m.getContacts().contains(contact))
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Parent::getParentField))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

and `getChild1List(Contact contact)` became:

```
    public List<Parent> getChild1List(Contact contact) {
        return returnsListByContact(child1List, contact);
    }
```

but now it doesn't like this, citing that getChild1List is returning a `List<Child1>`. I don't understand why, as the implementation of the stream was not altered at all - except that the childList which starts it came through a generic parameter, rather than a direct call to the private member field of MyClass.

So why do they return two different things?

Comment: I fixed the formatting. Use backquotes for code that is inlined, and indent by four spaces to format a block of code. If you want code to show an indent of four spaces, you have to add four spaces to format it as a block of code, and then add an *additional* four spaces for the indentation to be visible. Don't use tabs.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out how to get the blocks to stay solid when writing multiple lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(The example is confusing. Is `Meeting` really `Parent`?)

In the first version of `getChild1List`, the `collect(toList())` method is called on a `Stream<Child1>` and its target type -- determined by the return type of `getChild1List` -- is `List<Parent>`. This works, because it's allowed for a stream of type T to be collected by a collector of a supertype of T. More specifically, you're adding instances of type `Child1` to a `List<Parent>` which is type-safe and is permitted. You could just as well change the declaration of `getChild1List()` to return `List<Child1>` instead of `List<Parent>`.

You can see where the variance is allowed by looking at the declaration of `collect()` in `Stream<T>`:

```
<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
```

The `? super T` is what allows the variance.

Your declaration of `returnsListByContact`,

```
<T extends Parent> List<T> returnsListByContact(List<T> childList, ...)
```

does **not** allow variance. It takes a parameter of type `List<T>` and returns a `List<T>`. The parameter and return type must be identical. That's why there's a mismatch when you pass in a `List<Child1>` and try to return it from a method whose return type is `List<Parent>` -- those types are incompatible.

To fix this, you need to add some variance to your declaration of `returnsListByContact`. Here's how I'd do it:

```
<T extends Parent> List<T> returnsListByContact(List<? extends T> childList, ...)
```

This allows you to return a list of some type while passing in a list of some subtype, in this case returning `List<Parent>` while passing in `List<Child1>`, which is what I think you want.

Comment: plus one for the first sentence, I could not get my head around it too.

Comment: Yes, Meeting is the actual name - any instances of it were Parent. Edited my original code to be clearer. Thought I had purged my code of it, to ironically make this readable to the general population... too many hours in to this project....

Comment: Had time to process this and your fix worked wonderfully. I had thought that the `.collect()` 's return type was based on what you fed in to the `Stream`, and did not know that the return type of the method had any bearing on the result. Thank you so much!